# Is there a name to this formula? $\frac{(ab)-(cd)}{(a+b)-(c+d)}$

Tags: probability

> Is there a name to this formula?
>
> $$\frac{(ab)-(cd)}{(a+b)-(c+d)}$$

I've been using this formula in a certain game. Someone else had found it and it's widely used on spreadsheets of the relevant game. I'm curious if it's common enough that there's a name for it or even used for something else.

I'll try my best to explain how it has been used.

- A certain random value is generated in the game, which can be *estimated* in the game.
- A *30% estimation* results in a pair of minimum and maximum value ( $a$ and $c$ ).
- A *100% estimation* gives another pair of minimum and maximum value ( $b$ and $d$ ).
- The range of the *30% estimation* is always bigger than the *100% estimation*.

Apparently inputting these numbers into the formula results in a number which is really accurate to the actual generated value in the game. Is this made specifically by someone who had figured out how the game generates the number, or is this a common approximation formula?

If it's the latter, is there a name for it?

Comment: What do you mean by '30% estimation' and '100% estimation'?  Are those supposed to be confidence ranges?  (If so, a '100% estimation' would be an exact figure, wouldn't it?)

Comment: It's how the game names it, I can't tell you more unfortunately :( Let me try to give an example if it helps at all. 30% estimation: 400-800. 100% estimation: 500-700. The actual value that's later to be found is somewhere within 500-700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a name to this formula?
>
> $$\frac{(ab)-(cd)}{(a+b)-(c+d)}$$

Sure there is! The above expression is a name for it :)

In all seriousness, the formula does not seem too special, or manipulate to anything nicer. It certainly may be very significant for this particular game you are considering, but I doubt it has been defined or studied often before.